# AttributeError: module 'articles.views' has no attribute 'about'

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I've been following The Net Ninja Django tutorial on YT (as closely as possibly), but I've hit  bit of a snag adding my app (articles) url to the views.py of my main project (website). I keep receiving this error:

```
File "C:File\Path\ToProjects\web_app\website\articles\urls.py", line 6, in <module>
url(r'^about/$', views.about),
AttributeError: module 'articles.views' has no attribute 'about'
```

I've got Python 3.6 and my pip freeze output is as follows:

```
appdirs==1.4.4
asgiref==3.3.1
distlib==0.3.1
Django==3.1.5
filelock==3.0.12
importlib-metadata==3.1.1
importlib-resources==3.3.0
pytz==2020.5
six==1.15.0
sqlparse==0.4.1
virtualenv==20.2.1
zipp==3.4.0
```

urls.py in project folder:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
  url(r'^articles/', include('articles.urls')),
  url(r'^about/$', views.about),
  url(r'^$', views.homepage),

]
```

views.py in app folder:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render


def article_list(request):
    return render(request, 'articles/article_list.html')
```

urls.py from app folder:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.article_list),

]
```

Output of my [directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOb8O.png)

Any help is very welcome!

Comment: Do you have an about page?

Comment: your `views.py` does not have an `about` view and you are listing it in `urls.py`. There is also no `homepage` view.

Comment: Thank you for your help so far! I do have further questions about this though.

So I included an `about` view in the app (articles)  `views.py` file and the error has stopped and the article page is being returned fine, however, I don't fully understand why this is because I have an `about` view in the main project `views.py` file.
I have also made no mention of an `about` page within the `urls.py` file of the app folder.

Does an `about` view have to be included in every subsequent `views.py` file of every new app included within a project?